# PINRemoteImage delete cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiimageview

I'm using PINRemoteImage in my iOS App for setting image on UIImageView. I always have the same link for image, but in meantime image can change (I can upload different image), but whenever I call pin_setImageFromURL on UIImageView it always sets an old image (not if I delete app and reinstall it). I found out that calling [[[PINRemoteImageManager sharedImageManager] defaultImageCache] removeAllObjects] will delete image from cache but only when I close and reopen app, so does anyone known how to force app to update cache immediately after calling upper method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered this method to clear cache:

```
[[[PINRemoteImageManager sharedImageManager] cache] removeObjectForKey:
    [[PINRemoteImageManager sharedImageManager]cacheKeyForURL:your_URL processorKey:nil]];
```

So, in your `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` you can set again your ImageView with your_URL.

That did the trick at my side ;)

Comment: This appears to be the way to clear PINCache when using Texture + ASNetworkImageNode.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution in Swift for removing image from cache is:

```
import PINRemoteImage
import PINCache

if let cacheKey = PINRemoteImageManager.sharedImageManager().cacheKeyForURL(NSURL(string: "http://your-image-url"), processorKey: nil) {
    PINRemoteImageManager.sharedImageManager().cache.removeObjectForKey(cacheKey, block: nil)
}
```